# MYSQL Trigger Copy Entire Row while insert,update

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I have  two Table namely admin_user,admin_user_bak
the structure of the table admin_user is

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `admin_user` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_name` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `emailid` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `roll` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `modified` datetime NOT NULL,
  `last_login` datetime NOT NULL,
  `status` enum('active','inactive') NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

and structure of table admin_user_bak have all the fields of admin_user and additionally a field bak_user_id . its auto increment id..

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `admin_user_bak` (
  `bak_user_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_name` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `emailid` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `roll` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `modified` datetime NOT NULL,
  `last_login` datetime NOT NULL,
  `status` enum('active','inactive') NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`bak_user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

here my trigger is

```
CREATE TRIGGER ins_admin_user BEFORE UPDATE ON admin_user
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN

    INSERT INTO admin_user_bak (user_id,user_name,name,emailid,password,roll,created,modified,last_login,status) VALUES ( NEW.user_id, NEW.user_name, NEW.emailid, new.password, NEW.roll, NEW.created, NEW.modified, NEW.last_login, NEW.status);

  END
```

my purpose is i want to back up all events. insert update delete of a particular record. not all record. i write for insertion. its not working
any idea.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

i want a insertion trigger but you had written **update on** in your trigger so it's not work.

You use **INSERT ON**

```
CREATE TRIGGER ins_admin_user BEFORE INSERT ON admin_user
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN

    INSERT INTO admin_user_bak (user_id,user_name,name,emailid,password,roll,created,modified,last_login,status) VALUES ( old.user_id, old.user_name, old.emailid, old.password, old.roll, old.created, old.modified, old.last_login, old.status);

  END
```

Comment: are you sure change all keyword **NEW** to **OLD**